# "Not an Answer" Flag Vagueness

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, not-an-answer

[Answer in Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47777955/in-app-purchase-error-while-retrieving-information-from-server-df-aa-20/51086295#51086295)

I flagged this as not an answer because it seems better suited as a comment. The answer is basically just "Sometimes you can get this error because of x, try this". My reasoning for flagging this as not-an-answer is that this seems better suited as a comment asking the OP if they forgot to do this step, and then once they clarify- an answer could be posted regarding how to solve it with the additional information. It got declined

> flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an
>   altogether wrong answer

I decided to be more lenient with flagging as not-an-answer in reviews and then failed [this audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/20155355)

My reasoning for selecting "No Action Needed" was that although I believed it should be better suited as a comment it seemed extremely similar to the previous answer for which my flag got declined for.

Can someone help clear up the vagueness for me? If anything I think the answer I flagged is more of a comment than the answer in the audit- the answer in the audit seemed bad (and possibly wrong- I don't know enough about the subject area, but that doesn't warrant removal) but it seemed like more of an attempt towards an actual answer than the answer that got disputed.

Comment: @DavyM I have read that link and am confused how the audit answer is not an attempt to answer the question, however bad the answer may be, yet the question I flagged is deemed to be an answer.

Comment: I don't think the answer from the audit is a good example of not-an-answer.